# Multiprocessing with threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

when I trying to make my script multi-threading,

I've found out multiprocessing,

I wonder if there is a way to make multiprocessing work with threading?

- cpu 1 -> 3 threads(worker A,B,C)
- cpu 2 -> 3 threads(worker D,E,F)
- ...

Im trying to do it myself but I hit so much problems.

is there a way to make those two work together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generate a number of `Processes`, and then spawn `Threads` from inside them. Each Process can handle almost anything the standard interpreter thread can handle, so there's nothing stopping you from creating new Threads or even new Processes within each Process. As a minimal example:

```
def foo():
    print("Thread Executing!")

def bar():
    threads = []
    for _ in range(3): # each Process creates a number of new Threads
        thread = threading.Thread(target=foo) 
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    processes = []
    for _ in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar) # create a new Process
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Communication between threads can be handled within each `Process`, and communication between the Processes can be handled at the root interpreter level using Queues or Manager objects.

Comment: This code really helped me a lot!,
If I add Queue into this code, should I lock the processing or thread?

I assume if I lock the process I will stop 3 threads right?

Comment: @atth3burger91 It depends what you're trying to do. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), "queues are thread and process safe", so you don't have to worry about adding to the queue simultaneously. However, if you care about adding and retrieving in a particular order, you should either add a lock, or add identifiers to the objects you're passing to the Queue. Manager dicts can also be easier to use, although they're less lightweight.

Comment: Note that my original example is sloppy, because print is not thread-safe. Each print statement should have a `lock.acquire` and `lock.release` statement to prevent simultaneous writing to the output stream.

Comment: Process is not getting exited when using queues, how to close the process after the completion of the program.

Comment: You sure you call join right after start? I think you start then join them after?

Comment: this doesn't run on Windows for me, I get  `Can't pickle <function bar at 0x000002AF4BD8E700>`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `function` that takes a `process` and make it run 3 `threads` and then spawn your processes to target this `function`, for example:

```
def threader(process):
    for _ in range(3):
        threading.Thread(target=yourfunc).start()

def main():
    # spawn whatever processes here to target threader
```